# Go. CRUD. Динамическое имя пакета

Tags: golang, crud

всем привет!
есть точка входа. Парсим url и передаем на вход метода имя сущности:

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    cntl "./controller"
)

/**
  Main method
*/
func main() {
  request := mux.NewRouter()
  request.HandleFunc("/{entity}/{action:view|edit|delete}/{id}", ParceHandler)
  http.Handle("/", request)
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3030", nil))
}

/**
  Parcing url params and call nessaccary function 
*/
func ParceHandler(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(request)
    entity := vars["entity"] 
    cntl.showAll(entity)
}
```

**controller.go**

```
package controller

import (
    "fmt"
    User "../user"
    Post "../post"
)


func showAll(entityName string) {
    entityName.GetAll()
}
```

**user.go**

```
package user 

func getAll() {
     return []int{1,2}
}
```

**post.go**

```
package post 

func getAll() {
     return []int{3,4}
}
```

Вот как-то можно через имя переменной перейти к соответствующему алиасу контроллера и вызвать метод **getAll** из соответствующую пакета?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь работать с го как будто это руби.  Рекомендую отказаться от подобного подхода как можно скорее.  Иначе боль.

Comment: @Ainar-G , а есть вариант как реализовать единый CRUD для N сущностей?